# Use of a single member struct as an attribute with boost::spirit::karma generators

Tags: c++, boost

### Original Problem

The original problem is parsing/generation of the transport header of the RTSP protocol, see RFC 2326 12.39 Transport, Page 60. The transport header is defined of multiple transport specs, at least one, and either comma separated or by repetition of the transport header. The transport specs are again a complex text based language, which also could be structs. Since the solution is relevant for all one list of items based grammars in conjunction with the used library, an example was extracted, with foo instead of RTSP, `foo_struct` instead of Transport, and integers instead of transport specs.

### Generalised Problem

For the sake of an example assume we got a text based grammar/language for data exchange, like HTTP. But right now, this protocol called "foo" is consists of a comma separated list of numbers like "5,3,2" in decimal notation.

The internal representation of the data of this langauge in C++ is defined as `foo_struct`.

**A.** We want to parse individual `int`s from the list while also adding them as items to the `std::vector<int>`, inside of the struct `foo_struct::bar_vector`.

**B**. We want to generate a valid text string out from a `foo_struct`, so at the moment again just a list of comma separated numbers.

### Approach

The C++ library boost has a very powerfull parsing and generating section, called spirit, which has it subparts qi for parsing and karma for generating.

### Specific Problem

Qi and karma has some ways to make it easy for the user, to stuff the atomic items from the sub parsers/generators, like the number and list ones, into custom structs. This works well for structs which more than one member to put data into. However both libraries have some ugly caveats in the corner case of structs consisting simply out of one member, because then, they assume it follows the concepts of a container like `std::list` or `std::vector`

How to solve this for **A.** (Qi) was already discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/19823413/3537677, but now this code below solved this in a not so satisfying way for **B.** (Karma).

---

So all the code intents to do is to define the `foo_struct` with just one member, define the Qi grammar for demonstration purposes, like in the solution for A. and also a Karma Generator, which is the troublemaker.

The `main` routine is then just for demonstrating i.e. testing this example.

**The ugly solution for B.**

I have a one member struct that I am using with `boost::spirit::karma`, but, as far as I could get it to work, I have to use a  `boost::spirit::karma::attr_cast` with a coustom `boost::spirit::traits::transform_attribute<T, std::vector<u>>{static std::vector<U> pre (const &T)` function,

which is very ugly and error prone. 
**If you know how to write it as simple as in the parsing case, that would be much more readable i.e. maintainable.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

struct foo_struct {
    std::vector<int> bar_vector;

    foo_struct() = default;

    explicit foo_struct(std::vector<int> v) : bar_vector(std::move(v)) {}
};

template<typename Iterator>
struct foo_parser_grammar
        : ::boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, foo_struct()> {
    foo_parser_grammar() : foo_parser_grammar::base_type(start) {

        start %= boost::spirit::qi::as<std::vector<int>>()[
                boost::spirit::qi::int_ % ","];
    }

    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, foo_struct()> start;

};

namespace boost {
namespace spirit {
namespace traits {
template<>
struct transform_attribute<foo_struct const, std::vector<int>, karma::domain> {
    typedef int type;

    static std::vector<int> pre(foo_struct const &d) { return d.bar_vector; }
};
}
}
}

template<typename OutputIterator>
struct foo_generator_grammar : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<OutputIterator, foo_struct()> {
    foo_generator_grammar() : foo_generator_grammar::base_type(start) {

        start = boost::spirit::karma::attr_cast<std::vector<int>>(
                boost::spirit::karma::int_ % ",");

    }

    boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIterator, foo_struct()> start;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    foo_struct foo{};
    std::string input{"5,3,2"};
    foo_parser_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> parse_grammar{};

    boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), parse_grammar,
                                    boost::spirit::ascii::space, foo);

    std::cout << "Input\"";
    std::for_each(foo.bar_vector.cbegin(), foo.bar_vector.cend(), [](const auto &i) { std::cout << i << ","; });
    std::cout << "\"\n";

    std::string output;
    foo_generator_grammar<std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>> gen_grammar{};

    boost::spirit::karma::generate(std::back_inserter(output),
                                   gen_grammar, foo);

    std::cout << "Output\"" << output << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/023fe3ef59ecc614)</kbd>**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct foo_struct {
    std::vector<int> bar_vector;

    foo_struct(std::vector<int> v = {}) : bar_vector(std::move(v)) {}
};

#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(foo_struct, bar_vector)

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
template <typename Iterator>
struct foo_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, foo_struct()> {
    foo_parser() : foo_parser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;
        start = int_ % "," >> eps;
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, foo_struct()> start;
};

#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

template <typename OutputIterator>
struct foo_generator : karma::grammar<OutputIterator, foo_struct()> {
    foo_generator() : foo_generator::base_type(start) {
        using namespace karma;
        start = int_ % "," << eps;
    }

  private:
    karma::rule<OutputIterator, foo_struct()> start;
};

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    using Out = boost::spirit::ostream_iterator;
    std::string const input{ "5,3,2" };

    foo_struct foo;
    parse(input.begin(), input.end(), foo_parser<It>{}, foo);

    std::copy(begin(foo.bar_vector), end(foo.bar_vector), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout << "Input: ", ","));

    foo_generator<Out> gen;
    std::cout << "\nOutput: " << format(gen, foo) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Input: 5,3,2,
Output: 5,3,2
```

### Notes:

- The `eps` fix is based on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823413/spirit-qi-attribute-propagation-issue-with-single-member-struct
- You might have noticed that your grammar failed to skip whitespace. The reason was that the rules failed to declare a skipper (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965).

  I fixed it using my guideline that the grammar should be in charge of what is skippable, not the caller.
- Many call sites were simplified by relying on ADL for name lookup
- I elected to demo `karma::format` as a shorthand to generate to an output stream
- You should consider verifying that all input is consumed:

  ```
  start = int_ % "," >> eoi;
  ```

  It is convenient that now you can drop the `eps`, while you'll be told when remaining unparsed is not parsed:

  ```
  bool ok = parse(input.begin(), input.end(), foo_parser<It>{}, foo);
  ```

Comment: Added my comments in a nut-shell. If you have any questions, let me know

Comment: Thought of a rather important point about the lack of error handling and added that.